# Finding P(X<2) where X follows a normal distribution

Tags: descriptive-statistics

How can I calculate P(X<2) when X follows a normal distrubtion where the mean is 1.5 and the variance is 4.

The solution should be 59.87%

Comment: Most statistical software packages have functions for doing these calculations.  In R you can use `pnorm` and in Python there is `cdf` from `scipy.stats.norm`.

Comment: Questions on Stack Exchange are supposed to show "research effort"; can you tell us what you've tried so far to solve your problem?

Comment: googling "gaussian distribution calculator curve online" gives e.g.: http://onlinestatbook.com/2/calculators/normal_dist.html ; https://stattrek.com/online-calculator/normal.aspx ; https://www.mathportal.org/calculators/statistics-calculator/normal-distribution-calculator.php

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a homework problem, they probably want you to look at a [standard normal table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_normal_table#Cumulative_from_mean_(0_to_Z)). Start by finding $Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}=\frac{2-1.5}{2}=0.25$ and then look that value up in the linked table: row 0.2 and column +0.05 has a value of 0.09871. This means that $P(X<2)-.5=0.09871$, so $P(X<2)=0.59871$.

Comment: this is a good answer, but IMO it's generally better (see @gung's comment) to refrain from answering self-study questions until the questioners have conformed to the community norms ...